# log-linear model in R under multinomial scheme

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, log-linear

I am trying to fit a log-linear model. In short, we can fit a log-linear model when `family=poisson` in R. But when we condition on N, we have multinomial distribution i.e., log-linear model under the multinomial scheme. We have two types of multinomial sampling: multinomial and product multinomial (independent multinomial sampling).

My problem is: I can fit a model using `glm` or `loglin` for Poisson sampling. How can I fit a log-linear model (hierarchical or non-hierarchical) under multinomial sampling (both cases). How can I manipulate `glm` or `loglin` function for this problem?

Any helpful tips or links or references would be appreciated.

Comment: My first guess is that it probably doesn't make much difference in the typical real world application.

Comment: yes, we get the same estimates, no matter the sampling design we use. But the asymptotic variances (i.e., SE) are different under different sampling designs. My focus on SE, since I will do some hypothesis testing and construct the confidence interval. This is why I want to manipuate the `glm` or `loglin` functions under different sampling design, so that I can get the SE (est.) dirrectly .